# Structuring complex web forms in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is a good approach in ASP.NET MVC for implementing a complex form where sections of the form are shown and hidden based on a user's inputs?

My background is in Webforms. I am frequently asked to build forms where a user selects an option from a dropdown list, triggering a handful of new fields to appear. A different selection might cause a different set of fields to appear.

In the past, I would handle this scenario via an `UpdatePanel` and a wrapper `Panel` around the fields that I want to show or hide. Validation is automatically disabled when the fields are hidden.

Going forward, I'd like to make use of MVC's attribute-based model validation, but is it possible to make the validation conditional on the values of other properties?

Also, how can I handle the toggling of blocks of form fields? I know how to do it manually in jQuery, but I'm hoping there's an approach that ties in with validation and server-side code.

I am liking MVC much better overall, but I haven't figured out how to handle this type of scenario very well. Likely I just need to shift my thinking to fit better with the MVC approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh,

The first thing I's suggest is to make sure you use ViewModels for the pages that are mode complicated. A ViewModel is basically a Model you create for a specific View; for example, a ViewModel could be a composition of other classes.

As for dynamically changing the fields on your View, the best way is to use jQuery (or any other javascript library) to do it.

I also migrated from a web form environment and I know is difficult to change gears at the begining, but trust me, doing a simple jQuery even handler is much simpler than having to put in place a control panel and then the event handlers.

Not to mention that is much more efficient; update panels are after all making partial posts to the page, sometimes, with jQuery you don't even need to do that.

After a few projects with MVC, I actually now find it time consuming to go and do the Update Panels on web forms ;)

Hope this helps,
-Covo

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be the answer you're looking for, but I personally don't think complex forms are very user friendly in the first place and I always try to split them up into simpler forms where possible, or to simplify the form. I've come across many forms in websites where there are a raft of "fields" where there should really be a few questions for the user to answer. Simple stuff which gets to the point of what they want to achieve rather than the field values, along with a lot of application specific knowledge needed to set those fields to the right values.

If you still want to go ahead with a complex form, then as the other answers have already stated there are facilities provided by MVC to do that, but there isn't any set way. So, it's down to you to figure out what will work best for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional asp.net webforms did alot of "magic" for you whereas you have to be aware of the work that goes into creating the "magic" in asp.net MVC. The benefit is that with MVC you have more control over what is happening which can also enhance performance.

In asp.net webforms an UpdatePanel is used for ajax calls. If you need to got to the server asynchronously(without doing a full post back) then use ajax via JQuery. See below for example:

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "/YourController/YourAction",
                    success: function (obj) {
                       //any logic you want to do upon success
                    }
                });
```

The above example will do an ajax HTTP GET call to /YourController/YourAction.

In order to handle "toggling of blocks", if you don't need to go to the server for data and you simply want to do it on the client, then use simple jquery. JQuery has a function for toggling items.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way MVC works in contrast to Webforms you're stuck with the responsibility of really thinking about what happens on the client and what happens on the server separately as not a lot of meta-data is being passed back to give us that happy Webforms feeling.

However, there is a notion when using the built-in AJAX libraries when you render a form that you can have it auto do an update once it is posted. In a sense, it's saving you the JavaScript/JQuery because it "auto-wires" it up similar-ish to a Panel. In this way you could potentially look at progressively rendering your complex forms from the server as each section is edited, etc.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid.aspx

The relevant code example to give you an idea (unfortunately, it's not in the more readable Razor syntax):

The relevant line is the Ajax.BeginForm where the form tag is rendered. Once the form is posted, the MS AJAX library will auto update the element specified in "UpdateTargetId" specified in the form's AjaxOptions. In this case, the response will be placed into the SPAN element "textEntered" upon reply from the server. Here, you could progressively render more content to the user to fill out, perhaps another form, etc.

```
<h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
<p>
    Page Rendered: <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>
</p>
<span id="status">No Status</span>
<br />   
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Update Status", "GetStatus", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="status" }) %>
<br /><br />
<% using(Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForm", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="textEntered"})) { %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("textBox1","Enter text")%>  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br />
  <span id="textEntered">Nothing Entered</span>
<% } %>
```